# How to replace all same values of a group in a column (dataframe) according to another column without loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to replace all the same values in a group of values by 0 if there is a 1 in another column corresponding to this group.

Here is an example of the output I want, if there is a 1 in the Y column, I want all the group made of ones in the input column to be 0.
For speed problematic, I don't want to use any loop that cross every column value (assuming that my column can have thousands of values).

[image: The result I would like]

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you give example input code and example output code, it is not entirely clear what you want to achieve

Comment: Yes I put an example with a picture

Comment: @Lukx Hello, you said "if there is a 1 in the Y column, I want all the group made of ones in the input column to be 0" but there is a 1 in your Y column but at the frist line the input is one and the output is not 0 can you explain me why ?

Comment: @Lukx Yes I see, but it still is not clear how the output should be decided

Comment: @OmarAldakar if input == 1 and Y == 1, the whole group of ones in the input will be 0 in the output.

Comment: @sampers a group is just a group of ones in the input, if there is a 1 in the Y and this 1 corresponds to a 1 in the input, the whole group of ones will be 0 -> that's my wanted output

Comment: @Lukx It is not what you did in the image

Comment: @Lukx as your output contains almost only 0's, we do not have an example. Can you split it up to explain some cases

Comment: @sampers so : if input == 1 and Y == 1, the entire group made of ones in the input will be 0 in the output (if you prefer a group is a succession of ones in the input columns, and I want these groups to rest the same or the become 0 if there is a 1 corresponding in the Y column) so if input == 1 and Y == 0 nothing change the output will stay 1 for the entire group (like the first row it's a group made of one 1)

Comment: @ansev yes that's the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['output']=(df['Y'].ne(1)        
                     .groupby(df['input'].ne(df['input'].shift()).cumsum())
                     .transform('all')
                     .mul(df['input']))
```

or

```
((~df['Y'].eq(1)
          .groupby(df['input'].ne(df['input'].shift()).cumsum())
          .transform('any')).mul(df['input']))
```

Comment: how does 'any' or 'all' works? i can't find any documentation on that

Comment: check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html ,  `groupby.transform('any')` makes the same for each `SeriesGroup`